# Need suggestions while pushing changes on the existing heroku application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Currently I am working on one of the application (abc.com) which is deployed on the Heroku both staiging and production environments.

Now I have to deploy changes on the staging server.

When I start the working, I created a separate **dev** branch from master and pushed all the changes under dev branch.

Currently staging is working from **master** branch (Some changes are pushed on master by another developer).

So I need suggestions for following

1. Should I merge master into dev (master => dev) or dev to master (dev => master).
2. If I merge (master => dev), did I have to set all the environment variables.
3. And most important how can I take pull on the heroku.

Here is my application configuration

```
Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.2.11
```

Let me know anything need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some recommendations. You should look into adopting a standardized workflow. Having your friend (or anyone for that matter) pushing directly to master can cause a whole lot of pain. I'll leave a recommendation at the end of the post.

1. As you're not following any workflow, this doesn't really matter for now. If your code is fit for going into production, merge `dev` into `master`. If you're just playing around to test things out, merge `master` into `dev`.
2. No. Environment variables are set on the Heroku environment, or using something like the [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv). It does not matter which branch you use on Git. (If, by chance, your environment variables are checked into Git, please remove them now and read [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). You don't want sensitive data checked into your repository.)
3. If you want to deploy your `dev` branch to Heroku, simply use: `git push staging dev`. This assumes your Git remote is named `staging`. If you're unsure, use `git remote -v` to get the correct name.

A general rule we apply is that `master` should always be deployable. To accomplish this at my company, we use [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/). This might be worth looking into for a unified way of working with Git and deployment.